# ¿Por qué está mal este codigo?

Tags: python, pycharm

En mi clase de programación estamos realizando filtros de imagen donde deben ser requisitos que la imagen en cuestión se: gire, invierta (espejo), esté en escala de grises y se pueda deshacer lo hecho.
Mi problema es que terminé mi código, pero no deshace correctamente, intenté preguntar a mi profesor pero el tampoco sabe el problema, dice que no entiende el problema ya que el código de por sí no tiene ningún error; he intentado rehacer el código de nuevo, pero tampoco funciona...
Ya no se que hacer!!!
Uso python junto con pycharm (No se si eso sirve...)
También el enlace del zip donde están los 2 códigos base
https://github.com/PCP-CLC/PCP-CLC-2022/blob/main/Tareas/Tarea%202/Tarea%202%20-%20Filtros%20de%20imagen.zip
Aquí va mi código para saber si alguien consigue ayudarme :")

```
import PCPictures_gui
from PCPictures_gui import obtener_pixeles
from PCPictures_gui import esperar_click
from PCPictures_gui import actualizar_imagen
from PCPictures_gui import salir
base_datos = []

def girar(foto):
    filas = len(foto)
    columnas = len(foto[0])
    girado = []
    for recorrer_c in range(columnas):
        giro = []
        for recorrer_f in foto:
            giro.insert(0,recorrer_f[recorrer_c])
        girado.append(giro)
    return girado


def blaco_negro(foto):
    global base_datos
    base_datos.append(foto)
    filas = len(foto)
    columnas = len(foto[0])
    for recorrer_f in range(0,filas):
        for recorrer_c in range(0,columnas):
            pixel = foto[recorrer_f][recorrer_c]
            rojo = pixel[0]
            verde = pixel[1]
            azul = pixel[2]
            promedio = int((rojo+verde+azul)//3)
            colores_pix = (promedio,promedio,promedio)
            foto[recorrer_f][recorrer_c]=colores_pix
    base_datos.append(foto)
    return foto


def invertir(foto):
    columnas = len(foto[0])
    filas = len(foto)
    for recorrer_f in range(filas):
        for recorrer_c in range(int(columnas/2)):
            indice_opuesto = columnas - recorrer_c - 1
            opuesto = foto[recorrer_f][indice_opuesto]
            actual = foto[recorrer_f][recorrer_c]
            foto[recorrer_f][indice_opuesto] = actual
            foto[recorrer_f][recorrer_c] = opuesto
    return foto


def tarea():
    global base_datos
    while True:
        click = esperar_click()
        if click == 'girar':
            foto = girar(obtener_pixeles())
            if len(base_datos) == 0:
                base_datos.append(obtener_pixeles())
            base_datos.append(foto)
            actualizar_imagen(foto)

        elif click == 'gris':
            if len(base_datos) == 0:
                base_datos.append(obtener_pixeles())
            foto = blaco_negro(obtener_pixeles())
            actualizar_imagen(foto)

        elif click == 'invertir':
            foto = invertir(obtener_pixeles())
            if len(base_datos) == 0:
                base_datos.append(obtener_pixeles())
            base_datos.append(foto)
            actualizar_imagen(foto)

        elif click == 'deshacer':
            if len(base_datos) == 1:
                foto = base_datos[0]
                actualizar_imagen(foto)
                continue
            if len(base_datos) != 1:
                base_datos.pop(-1)
                foto = base_datos[-1]
                actualizar_imagen(foto)

        elif click == 'salir':
            salir()
app = PCPictures_gui.Application("tarea")
app.title('PCPictures CLC 2022')
app.loadProgram(tarea)
app.start()
tarea()
```

Comment: Buen día, intenté descargar la librería `PCPictures_gui` y dice que no existe. ¿Es alguna librería local en tu PC? ¿Qué versión de Python utilizas?

Comment: Tecnicamente lo de PCP pictures no debería ser el problema... pero si quieres puedo enviarte el link de github, ahí hay un ziper con todo 
https://github.com/PCP-CLC/PCP-CLC-2022/tree/main/Tareas/Tarea%202
la version de phyton es la 2022.2